# iOS app rejected from apple app store because UIWebview

Tags: ios, iphone, uiwebview, review

Got App rejection reason from Apple:

> Upon further review, we noticed that your app only includes links, images, or content aggregated from the Internet with limited or no native iOS functionality. We understand that this content may be curated from the web specifically for your users, but since it does not sufficiently differ from a mobile web browsing experience, it is not appropriate for the App Store.

Basically, we are using UIWebview and safari as well. for show content, we are using UIWebview. and on click of a banner, we are opening a link in safari. I have already give explanation like

> We have one admin panel from where we are adding this detail. But based on our requirement we need to redirect a user to specific link or show content. and for make things easy we have used HTML content. But we have used web view in detail page only. Rest of the screen have Native iOS functionality.
>
> So basically we are not fetching website data. we are showing our own backend panel detail in the application.

But still, they rejected the app.

Comment: We can't help you. If Apple feels you don't have enough content, that's their choice. We can't affect it. If you can't show them it's not just a web view, that's it.

Comment: I agree. But I feel that they don't have a problem with content. But they have a problem with a way of implementation. I feel that they want me to add all link redirection inside app only. because some links open in safari and some links are open inside an app. Please let me know if I am wrong at any point. Becuase anyhow I want to fix this issue and make app live :)

Comment: Apple strict on its rules. It won't allow loading too many web views. I understood your requirement of controlling from the backend. But It won't help you to accept the app on app store. One way to resolve this by limiting web views and the other is to send an update again with a proper explanation. App reviewer changes every time. There are chances of your app to be accepted if the reviewer is not strict on this.

Comment: Let me try your suggestion. Thanks @SivajeeBattina

Comment: @AnkitaGuna: One more solution would be to add a native app login, maybe some social login like `Login using Facebook` on first viewcontroller and then upon login second viewcontroller would load the page.

Comment: @AnkitaGuna : Do one thing instead of showing only uiwebview, arrange your data like a news reading app, there you can use tableview to arrange and then forward it into web view.

Comment: @DeepakKumarSahu This solution is also not working.

Comment: @AnkitaGuna : What bad now?

Answer (score 3):

I'm in the same predicament with my app (it grabs content from my company's website like pictures and text and displays it in a native way). To be clear, I'm not using any webviews to display the content except for the Videos tab (see below).

I wanted to share what I've done so far to make it more "native", so you won't waste your time. My application is tabbed, by the way (Research, Blog Posts, Events, Videos, Bookmarks).

- Added offline reading capabilities with Bookmarks to read blog posts and research summaries
- Added SpeechSynthesizer so reports could be read to the user
- Added push notifications for when new content was released
- Removed UIWebViews and replaced with Safari Services (I am using WKWebView to embed videos into UITableView though)

Unfortunately, none of that has worked.

Comment: This worked for me: using UIDocumentViewController (for previewing documents like PDFs), UIActivityViewController (for sharing on social media, etc.), SpeechSynthesizer (for it to read my previews in audio) are the three native APIs I used, oh and the Calendar one, which I can't remember the name for.